# How can I properly write SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL querybut am not sure how to properly do what I want to achieve. Right now I have

```
select id 
from job 
where status = 'NE' 
    or status = 'RU' 
    and queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
    or queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId);
```

so basically if the job has a status of NE or a status of RU and queue matches either concat string then it should produce a result.

Comment: You might want to put some parentheses around the various terms of the `where` clause to be sure they are evaluated with the associations you expect.  Otherwise, your query looks good!

Comment: `(status = 'NE' 
    or status = 'RU' )
    and (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
    or queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));` seperate the OR condition by ()..check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use parentheses to group together clauses.

```
select id 
from job 
where 
    (status = 'NE' or status = 'RU')
    and (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
    or queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing Parenthesis.

```
select id 
from job 
where (status = 'NE' 
    or status = 'RU' )
    and (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
    or queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));
```

or

```
select id 
from job 
where status in( 'NE','RU' )
    and (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
    or queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your where condition the `OR` condition should seperated from `AND` using (),So the OR condition will check first and it will combine with AND

```
select id 
from job 
        where (status = 'NE' or status = 'RU' ) and 
    (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) or 
    queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters missing, needed to group clauses. Also this is the general format, if that's something you needed too.

```
SELECT id 
  FROM job 
 WHERE status IN( 'NE','RU' )
       AND (queue = CONCAT('VA-', varVappId) 
       OR queue = CONCAT('CL-', varClientId, '||', 'VA-', varVappId));
```